# Laravel - json_encode() não funciona

Tags: json, array, laravel

Trazer para o Laravel em formato de array.

```
[compacto] => {"version":"4.5.0","objects":[{"type":"group","version":"4.5.0","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":567,"top":313,"width":48,"height":48,"fill":"rgb(0,0,0)","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":0,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeDashOffset":0,"strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeUniform":false,"strokeMiterLimit":4,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","paintFirst":"fill","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","skewX":0,"skewY":0,"objects":[{"type":"image","version":"4.5.0","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":-24,"top":-24,"width":48,"height":48,"fill":"rgb(0,0,0)","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":0,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeDashOffset":0,"strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeUniform":false,"strokeMiterLimit":4,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","paintFirst":"fill","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","skewX":0,"skewY":0,"cropX":0,"cropY":0,"src":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/img/icone_marker.png","crossOrigin":null,"filters":[]},{"type":"text","version":"4.5.0","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":-14,"top":-19,"width":24.01,"height":40.68,"fill":"black","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeDashOffset":0,"strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeUniform":false,"strokeMiterLimit":4,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","paintFirst":"fill","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","skewX":0,"skewY":0,"text":"1","fontSize":36,"fontWeight":"normal","fontFamily":"Arial Black","fontStyle":"normal","lineHeight":1.16,"underline":false,"overline":false,"linethrough":false,"textAlign":"left","textBackgroundColor":"","charSpacing":0,"path":null,"direction":"ltr","styles":{}}]},{"type":"group","version":"4.5.0","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":430,"top":844,"width":59.02,"height":48,"fill":"rgb(0,0,0)","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":0,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeDashOffset":0,"strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeUniform":false,"strokeMiterLimit":4,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","paintFirst":"fill","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","skewX":0,"skewY":0,"objects":[{"type":"image","version":"4.5.0","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":-29.51,"top":-24,"width":48,"height":48,"fill":"rgb(0,0,0)","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":0,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeDashOffset":0,"strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeUniform":false,"strokeMiterLimit":4,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","paintFirst":"fill","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","skewX":0,"skewY":0,"cropX":0,"cropY":0,"src":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/img/icone_marker.png","crossOrigin":null,"filters":[]},{"type":"text","version":"4.5.0","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":-19.51,"top":-19,"width":48.02,"height":40.68,"fill":"black","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeDashOffset":0,"strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeUniform":false,"strokeMiterLimit":4,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","paintFirst":"fill","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","skewX":0,"skewY":0,"text":"65","fontSize":36,"fontWeight":"normal","fontFamily":"Arial Black","fontStyle":"normal","lineHeight":1.16,"underline":false,"overline":false,"linethrough":false,"textAlign":"left","textBackgroundColor":"","charSpacing":0,"path":null,"direction":"ltr","styles":{}}]},{"type":"group","version":"4.5.0","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":214,"top":386,"width":48,"height":48,"fill":"rgb(0,0,0)","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":0,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeDashOffset":0,"strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeUniform":false,"strokeMiterLimit":4,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","paintFirst":"fill","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","skewX":0,"skewY":0,"objects":[{"type":"image","version":"4.5.0","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":-24,"top":-24,"width":48,"height":48,"fill":"rgb(0,0,0)","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":0,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeDashOffset":0,"strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeUniform":false,"strokeMiterLimit":4,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","paintFirst":"fill","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","skewX":0,"skewY":0,"cropX":0,"cropY":0,"src":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/img/icone_marker.png","crossOrigin":null,"filters":[]},{"type":"text","version":"4.5.0","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":-14,"top":-19,"width":24.01,"height":40.68,"fill":"black","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeDashOffset":0,"strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeUniform":false,"strokeMiterLimit":4,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","paintFirst":"fill","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","skewX":0,"skewY":0,"text":"3","fontSize":36,"fontWeight":"normal","fontFamily":"Arial Black","fontStyle":"normal","lineHeight":1.16,"underline":false,"overline":false,"linethrough":false,"textAlign":"left","textBackgroundColor":"","charSpacing":0,"path":null,"direction":"ltr","styles":{}}]}],"backgroundImage":{"type":"image","version":"4.5.0","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":0,"top":0,"width":3840,"height":2160,"fill":"rgb(0,0,0)","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":0,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeDashOffset":0,"strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeUniform":false,"strokeMiterLimit":4,"scaleX":0.5,"scaleY":0.43,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","paintFirst":"fill","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","skewX":0,"skewY":0,"cropX":0,"cropY":0,"src":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploads/imagens/mapa_dia/original/5XZn382CynGFeV21uSsZpTup3b57DF3Hsy53cJZW.png","crossOrigin":null,"filters":[]}}
```

Esse é o erro apresentado com json_decode()

> ErrorException json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array
> given

De que forma consigo?

Answer (score 2):

`json_decode`, como você pode ver na [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php), serve para decodificar uma string JSON. Ou seja, a menos você tenha uma string JSON, não deve funcionar.

Eis um exemplo:

```php
$string = "{\"version\": \"4.5.0\", \"objects\": {}}";
$decode = json_decode($string);
```

Não tenho certeza sobre o que esse trecho de código que você citou representa, mas caso você tenha um array e queira converter isso em uma string JSON, você deve usar `json_encode` ([veja a documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php)).

Um exemplo:

```php
$array = ['versao' => '4.5.0', 'objects' => []];
$encode = json_encode($array);
```

Se for interessante, veja [um exemplo funcional](https://phpsandbox.io/n/white-disk-7mem-cjtzj).